# AWS lambda post mysql duplicate key but no error, why?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, promise, async-await

In mysql table i have created, I set autoincrement and unique value for the primary key. It is 
I ran the following code multiple times. it is suppose to show error most of the time due to repetitive keys entered, however, there was no error.

```html
exports.handler = async (event) => {
var mysql = require('mysql');
  
    // TODO implement
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : '-',
  user     : '-',
  password : '-',
  database : '-'
});

const sql = `INSERT INTO forms VALUES(20,2,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11);`;
connection.query(sql, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
})
const wait = () => {
    setTimeout(()=>console.log('timeout'),2000)
}
await wait();
await console.log(sql)

const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
return response;
};
```

It is suppose to show error as below
[image: Suppose to show error due to duplicate entry]

But it shows no error most of the time.Why?
[image: No error most of the time]

Comment: how did you get it to error correctly the first time?

Comment: it's supposed to show error, as it is not recorded in the database. but it's not showing, even though the code passes erroneously.